# Infrared divergences: total energy of soft photons

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization, infrared-radiation, infrared-divergences

One way to deal with IR-divergences in QED is sum over soft photons, which can't be detected due to finite sensitivity of detector: only photons with energy bigger that resolution of detector $E>E_{min}$ can be detected.

**How to deal with possibility of situation, when sum energy $E_{tot}$ of soft photons is compatible with energy of hard particles?**

Comment: I think the idea is to define a soft energy scale, such that not only the energy carried by a single photon be non-detectable. But instead, define the scale in a way such that if there are even infinitely many soft photons produced during an arbitrary scattering process, their combined energy is less than that scale...